# Can anyone detect why my jQuery is firing on my homepage, but isn't firing on a different page within the same domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been having some issues getting jQuery to work on some parts of my website. To test if the jQuery would fire I prepared a bit of jQuery that launches everytime my header file is included.

When I am at the home page the jQuery fires properly and the pop-up comes up. As soon as I move to a different section of the site. The same jQuery code included in the header isn't firing. I have checked the console for errors or faults and couldn't find anything.

A test location of the website would be at [this location](http://geluk.geldpaleis.nl/webshop/)

That is the homepage of the site, if you visit it a pop-up will appear. If you browse to [this link](http://geluk.geldpaleis.nl/webshop/categories/snoep)  the jQuery doesn't fire even though it's still there in the code.

The jQuery code I'm trying to launch is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeIn(200,function(){
                    $('#box2').fadeIn(400)
                });
                return false;
            });          
</script>
```

I'm not very experienced in debugging jQuery and have tried consulting some other questions and forums thought these solutions or attempts didn't seem to work for me. I was hoping I could get a hint in the right direction here.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools.  They will reveal any syntax errors which may prevent this code from executing at all.  If there are no syntax errors, set breakpoints elsewhere in your code to see if you can see where it's stopping.  Set break points and make sure that the elements you want (`#overlay`) exist at the time you expect them to.

Comment: Looking at the console, I see an error.  Something is triggering an error within the `s3Slider.js` file.

Comment: There are a number of things that can cause problems. IF there was an error in the javascript code earlier on the page, this won't run. If the items you are referencing haven't loaded but the page tries to run the script it won't work properly. this is why the browser dev tools can be helpful (my second point is why so much jQuery has `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @Sparky I'm gonna try and disable the slider .js file and see if it'll work.

Comment: @Brad I've tried using the chrome and firefox tools to detect errors but none were given. Do you have any suggested plugins or alternative tools that are helpful or more in depth?

Comment: There are most definitely errors given... maybe you did not look in the right place?

Comment: @TomKriek I use the developer tools built into Chrome and need no others.  They are sufficient, and quite robust for JavaScript development.

Comment: @Sparky I think I'm going blind I've seen the slider.js error now and resolved it. The jQuery I wanted to run is now doing it's job.

Comment: @TomKriek A common mistake I see with new folks to web development is opening the developer tools after the page is loaded.  Be sure to open those tools and then refresh the page to make sure you catch everything.  Otherwise, only the most severe errors will be displayed and you will miss much of the network traffic.

Comment: @Brad Thanks I'm normally more into PHP and server sided programming and guess I got kind of used to errors being presented to me on a platter. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @TomKriek Oh, they still are.  You just have to get familiar with a new debugging method.  Also, if you want client-side errors logged server-side, there are tools and services available that do that.  But, it's often easier just to solve problems in-browser since that's where you have to fix and test them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider2').s3Slider({
        timeOut: 4000
    });
});
```

appears to be raising an error which causes the javascript processing to stop.  The element '#slider2' element does not exist on this page.  Either remove this code or add a guard condition such as,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#slider2').length) {
      $('#slider2').s3Slider({
          timeOut: 4000
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I've resolved the issue thanks to Sparky pointing me to something I should have definitely seen before. I'm going to try your method as well. Thanks for the help.